# Javascript function to update a countdown timer automatically in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

```
def time_remaining
    Time.at(6.hours.since - Time.now)
  end

  def timer
    time_remaining.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
```

I have this in my controller, `time_remaining` should change every time the page is reloaded, but i have been trying to get a javascript function that would just do the countdown automatically without reloading. And also how do i get a link to display `time_remaining` in erb

Comment: that would require ajax ? and since you have `%s` I'm assuming that you would want it to do an ajax request every second .. better to implement the countdown timer in javascript

Comment: could you provide the code example to do the ajax request every second or better yet, explain a way to implement the countdown timer in javascript?